Adding a child entity to parent's collection fails during a second call to SaveChanges() in Entity Framework Core
I have a parent/child relationship in EF Core and I want to add a parent entity, save changes, then add a child to that parent and save the changes again (Note: This is part of a much more complex code that runs in a transaction and needs the intermediate SaveChanges, but here I have extracted only the code needed to show the problem).
If I add a child to the new parent before the first SaveChanges call, it works fine. However, if I add it after the first SaveChanges call, I get an error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

This worked fine in Entity Framework (non-Core), but now fails in EF Core.
If I manually add the child entity to the appropriate db set (instead of the children's collection), it works fine.
Is there anything I can do to fix this on a general level, e.g. by configuring the context in a different way?
Here is the full code to simulate the problem:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Empty everything from previous runs
        {
            using var db = new BloggingContext();
            var posts = db.Posts.ToList();
            var blogs = db.Blogs.ToList();

            foreach (var post in posts)
                db.Remove(post);

            foreach (var blog in blogs)
                db.Remove(blog);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        try
        {
            using var db = new BloggingContext();

            var blog = new Blog
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Blog 1",
                SiteUri = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet",
                Posts = new List<Post>()
            };

            db.Add(blog);

            var post1 = new Post
            {
                Id = 11,
                BlogId = 1,
                Title = "Hello World",
                Content = "I wrote an app using EF Core!"
            };

            blog.Posts.Add(post1);

            db.SaveChanges();

            var post2 = new Post
            {
                Id = 12,
                BlogId = 1,
                Title = "Hello World 2",
                Content = "I wrote an app using EF Core 2!"
            };

            blog.Posts.Add(post2);
            // db.Posts.Add(post2); --> With this line it works

            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SiteUri { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public BloggingContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlServer($"Server=.;Database=DbTests;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Posts)
            .WithOne(e => e.Blog)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BlogId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}

And the SQL for the database model:
CREATE TABLE [Blogs] 
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [SiteUri] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Blogs] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Posts] 
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Title] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [PublishedOn] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [Archived] bit NOT NULL,
    [BlogId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Posts] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_Blogs_BlogId] FOREIGN KEY ([BlogId]) REFERENCES [Blogs] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


You should use not BlogId, but assign Blog navigation property for post. Then possible multiple SaveChanges will be not needed.

It is assigned in the opposite direction, which is a legitimate way of doing it. Multiple SaveChanges are needed because of other logic and are also legitimate and supported by EF core.

Do not assign BlogId then, EF Core should do that automatically.

I tried it, no change in the behavior.

For default, EF Core treat Primary Key as generated from database. In you sample code, PK is generated from client. The cause root is you forgot to config this.
In your case, use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] for Id of Blog and Post, or using corresponding Fluent API configuration in DbContext.

This does not affect the problem. The problem is in the entity tacking (not marked as new but somehow still expected to be inserted) and not the actual connection between the entities. Also, manually assigned ids are completely supported by EF core and used here only for simplicity.

well, could you check again your minimum repro.  In db.SaveChanges() for post2, ef core create an update query instead of insert query. My solution will resolve this issue and it worked without error. You can add options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine); to see the generated queries.

I use sql server and .net 7 for testing.

It is correct that EF core generates an update statement for post2 instead of an insert statement. The call for post1 is correct (insert) although they are added in the exact same way. Seems like EF does not track the new entity correctly. Calling this code also seems to fix the problem:
db.Entry(post2).State = EntityState.Added;
I cannot change the id to be generated by the database because that is not how the application works and changing that is not an option (it's a big application).

Maybe you are misunderstanding my solution, it DO NOT config the Id is generated by database. It DO let EF Core know Id IS NOT set by database, Id will be set in client side as in the minimum repro.

If your problem is DatabaseGenerated attribute is not available in Core layer, you can use fluent api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api#no-value-generation

You are right, I misunderstood your solution. I tried this and it works. I don't know why this causes EF core to consider the new post as "modified" instead of "added" but your solution fixes it.
